# Im getting this exception in dart code where Im using carousel slider. It says "Null check operator used on a null value"

Tags: flutter, dart

```
return AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: carouselState!.pageController!,
          child: (widget.items != null)
              ? (widget.items!.length > 0 ? widget.items![index] : Container())
             //exception at this line : widget.itemBuilder!(context, index, idx),
          builder: (BuildContext context, child) {
            double distortionValue = 1.0;
            // if `enlargeCenterPage` is true, we must calculate the carousel item's height
            // to display the visual effect
            if (widget.options.enlargeCenterPage != null &&
                widget.options.enlargeCenterPage == true) {
              double itemOffset;
```

Comment: could you please add the full code of this widget also contain the constructor property?

Answer (score 0):

I think you issue is in your null check. You forgot else state in your first check.

```
(widget.items != null) ?  ():(you forgot this part)
```

So change it to something like this:

```
child: widget.items != null
              ? (widget.items!.length > 0
                  ? Text('${widget.items![index]}')
                  : Container())
              : Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
```